# How do I get the number of lines for specific files in a large directory?

Tags: linux, bash, console-application

I have the command "find . -name '*.dmp' | xargs wc -l" to get the lines from all the dmp files in a directory. The dump files naming convention is "dump-10181.dmp" with the number being a unique incremental number.

How do I get the number of lines for only files with the number 50 - 678?

Comment: This: `wc -l dump-{50..678}.dmp`

Comment: And if for instance your interested in 50..300 and 400..678 you may try this: `wc -l dump-{{50..300},{400..768}}.dmp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
seq 50 678 | xargs -I'{}' cat dump{} | wc -l
```

Answer (score 1):

Longer than other solutions but more general:

```
for f in *.dmp ; do \
    n=${f##*-}; n=${n%.dmp}; \
    [[ "$n" = "" || "$n" = *[^0-9]* ]] && continue ;\
    n=$((10#$n)) ; ((n >= 50 && n <= 678)) && cat "./$f" ;\
done | wc -l
```

Comment: Please give me examples of issues! I added all these backslashes and semicolumns to get something readable.

Comment: Fixed; do you see other issues?

Comment: Ça m'a l'air bon `;)`.